# How to get this authoryear-like citation/bibliography style?

Tags: biblatex

[I really like the citations and the bibliography of this document.](https://hses.bsz-bw.de/files/69/Prekarisierung_und_die_Rolle_der_Sozialen_Arbeit.pdf)

I've been running this style so far:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-icomp,firstinits=true,ibidpage=true]{biblatex}
```

With this (and some tweaks) I am close but not yet there.

Can anyone help me?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear-icomp,firstinits=true,ibidpage=true]{biblatex} 
\usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{doerre,
  title     = {Bewährungsproben für die Unterschicht?},
  publisher = {Campus-Verl.},
  year      = {2013},
  author    = {Dörre, Klaus},
  series    = {International labour studies},
  address   = {Frankfurt am Main [u.a.]},
  pages     = {423 S.},
  subtitle  = {soziale Folgen aktivierender Arbeitsmarktpolitik},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

test \textcite{doerre}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: (1) welcome, (2) erh, since we are out of crystal balls, you might need to be a bit (a lot) more specific

Comment: Your question is completely unclear. We do neither know what you have nor what you want. Please show us a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography) and describe in detail the difference you want and the problems with your own suggestions to achieve the wanted results.

Comment: forgot the link for the example, sorry

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be a fairly normal `authoryear`-like style with a few modifications.

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage[german=guillemets]{csquotes} 
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, maxbibnames=999, maxcitenames=2, mincitenames=1]{biblatex} 

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{doerre,
  title     = {Bewährungsproben für die Unterschicht?},
  publisher = {Campus-Verl.},
  year      = {2013},
  author    = {Dörre, Klaus},
  series    = {International labour studies},
  address   = {Frankfurt am Main},
  pagetotal = {423},
  subtitle  = {Soziale Folgen aktivierender Arbeitsmarktpolitik},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}{\textsc}

\renewcommand*{\multinamedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}%
\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{\addspace\bibstring{and}\space}%

\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat{multipostnote}{#1}

\DeclareNameAlias{sortname}{family-given}

\DefineBibliographyStrings{german}{and = {u\adddot}}


\begin{document}
test \autocite{doerre} lorem \autocite{sigfridsson,worman,companion}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]
I could not find evidence of the style using 'ibid' or compression features, so I went with `authoryear` as basis.